# Generic webhook Trigger plugin to build based on files and specific branch

Tags: jenkins

I have generic webhook trigger plugin in Jenkins. I have to build based on files changed on a specific branch on the repo. Let me know.
I use Github and jenkins.

```
variable: changed_files Expression: $.commits[*]. 
['modified','added','removed'][*]
variable: ref Expression: $.ref
```

In Option Filter
I have these

```
text: $ref $changed_files
Expression: (^refs/heads/develop)\s"local/test/[^"]+?"
```

**result:** Build not getting triggered though Json has proper values.

In Option filter 
I have these

```
text: $changed_files
Expression: "local/test/[^"]+?"
```

**result:** build is getting triggered irrespective of the branch.

Please let me know how to configure  Option filter expressions.
Let me know how i can checkout only the branch on which commit has happened in the repo. I have using pipeline jobs.

Comment: Does `text: $ref` `Expression: ^refs/heads/develop` only trigger the pipeline ? If no, what is the output of $ref ?

Comment: output of $ref is refs/heads/testing_generic

Comment: I need to build the expression in the option filter to capture changed_files and the branch which is not working at present,

Comment: If your output of $ref is refs/heads/testing_generic then pipeline won't trigger as it doesn't match the expression and it's working as expected then.

Comment: ok. If i change the expression like this (^refs/heads/testing_generic)\s"local/test/[^"]+?"  then also the build is not getting triggered.

Comment: Basically the expression should catch changed_files and the comitted branch and trigger the build but its not triggering.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. Can you output both `$ref $changed_files` and post what you see ?

Comment: Contributing variables:

    changed_files = ["local/test/a"]
    changed_files_0 = local/test/a
    ref = refs/heads/testing_generic

Answer (score 2):

Variable `changed_files` set to `$.commits[*].['modified','added','removed'][*]`

Variable `ref` set to `$.ref`

Filter `text` as `$ref $changed_files`

Filter `expression` as `refs/heads/develop .*"local/test/[^"]+?".*`

There is a test case showing this feature here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gwt/bdd/github/github-push-trigger-when-specific-file-changes-to-branch.feature

Comment: Thanks. This was created after i have raised an issue in that project.